# Is it possible to make a Grid with lines (45 degrees) diagonal to the main grid plane using GeoNodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to instance cubes on a grid with lines diagonal orientation to the main grid (created by GeoNodes). It is possible to rotate instances but couldn't manage a clean shape with variable grid parameters etc..
I thought it would be best if it was possible to make the grid itself with diagonal lines (45 degrees).. is it possible?

[image]

Comment: IF you are using a grid to instance the cubes on, then you could just add a transform node after the grid node and then instance the cubes.

Comment: I did just that, but it is never clean. The problem I presented is just a part of more complex one using two sets of instances imposed on grids, and I thought it would be very helpful if we can make the grid itself with diagonal lines, and that's why I asked

Answer (score 4):

Just rotate the grid 45 deg using transform. If needed, you can trim it like this:

[image]

Comment: looks great @Crantisz, but I couldn't find the node "Less Than" with "Vector".. etc ?

Comment: I think I got it.. I replaced it with the shown set of nodes and it did work.

Comment: it is "compare" node

Comment: ok, thank you.. I am happy with your solution

Answer (score 3):

i assume, you want this?

[image]

result:

[image]

basically i just do 2 dumb nested loops - over x and y which i recalculate to the index of the points of the grid. Then with that calculated index i get the position of the point in the grid and create and position the mesh lines by set position.

Comment: Yes this looks great!. I will try it, and let you know :)

Comment: It seems to me too complex for my purpose..  I don't need the animation part @Chris , though I need it to be variable, so can you please indicate which nodes are irrelevant, because the purpose of many nodes is not clear. this will save me a lot of time if you be kind enough to further help me

Answer (score 0):

You can skew the grid by offsetting the vertices on $x$ coordinate in relation to $y$ coordinate, or vice-versa. The question then becomes, what is the proportion between the two:

[image]

Clearly, for the $45°$ the relation is $1$:

[image]

Grid properties are hidden, because they are irrelevant to the effect, you can change them and the skewing will still give $45°$ angle.

And here's a triangulated grid, which has the diagonal $45°$ lines:

[image]

Comment: No, I need the grid to remain rectangular, only the dividing lines be diagonal

Comment: @SaiebKhalil can you sketch what you want to achieve?

Comment: sorry @Markus, I just forgot how to publish images, and couldn't find out... 
imagine a rectangular shape with diagonal dividing lines

Comment: This reminds me 7 red lines https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg objective is not clear

Comment: @SaiebKhalil see edit.

Comment: great... I found it and published the  image